# How to force MultiIndex level to dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I use `combine_first` to combine two DataFrames based on two keys, the goal is to append the indices of df2 that are not contained in df1 to the result and to overwrite indices that are contained in both with the values from df2.

Example df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "key1": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
    "id": ["a1", "a2", "a3", 1, 2, "c1", "c2"],
    "data1": [pd.np.random.randint(5) for i in range(7)],
    "data2": [pd.np.random.randint(1000) for i in range(7)]
})
```

Example df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "key1": ["B", "B", "B"],
    "id": [2, 3, 4],
    "data1": [pd.np.random.randint(5) for i in range(3)],
    "data2": [pd.np.random.randint(1000) for i in range(3)]
})
```

`df1.set_index(["key1", "id"]).combine_first(df2.set_index(["key1", "id"]))` gives the desired result:

```
         data1  data2
key1 id              
A    a1    0.0  588.0
     a2    2.0  709.0
     a3    3.0  877.0
B    1     3.0  468.0
     2     0.0  612.0
     3     2.0  139.0
     4     3.0  154.0
C    c1    4.0  855.0
     c2    4.0  564.0
```

However, after storing the result as csv, loading it again and running the same command I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

But only for a df2 where `id` is `int` only. When `id` contains characters it works without a problem.

I found [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) in the Pandas docs:

> The different indexing operation can potentially change the dtype of a
>   Series.

Which explains why the problem persists if I change the dtype of `df2.id` to `object` before setting the index and combining. How can I specifically set the dtype of a MultiIndex level so that the combination works?

---

**EDIT**
To further illustrate the problem:

```
df = df1.set_index(["key1", "id"]).combine_first(df2.set_index(["key1", "id"]))
df.to_csv("tests/combtest2.csv", sep=";")
df_loaded = pd.read_csv("tests/combtest2.csv", sep=";", index_col=["key1", "id"])
```

Looks fine:

```
         data1  data2
key1 id              
A    a1    0.0  588.0
     a2    2.0  709.0
     a3    3.0  877.0
B    1     3.0  468.0
     2     0.0  612.0
     3     2.0  139.0
     4     3.0  154.0
C    c1    4.0  855.0
     c2    4.0  564.0
```

But `df_loaded.combine_first(df2.set_index(["key1", "id"]))` results in:

```
         data1  data2
key1 id              
A    a1    0.0  588.0
     a2    2.0  709.0
     a3    3.0  877.0
B    1     3.0  468.0
     2     0.0  612.0
     3     2.0  139.0
     4     3.0  154.0
C    c1    4.0  855.0
     c2    4.0  564.0
B    2     2.0  317.0
     3     2.0  139.0
     4     3.0  154.0
```

Comment: As a workaround, I resorted to first combining all the old and new observations for a certain `key1` and then appending them to get the final result. I'd prefer not to include that additional step though, and just set the level(1) dtype of `df2` to object.

Comment: Are you sure that changing the `dtype` of `df2.id` to `object` before setting the index and combining doesn't solve the problem? I've just tried it and it worked.

Comment: What I tried: `df2.id = df2.id.astype(str); df_loaded.combine_first(df2.set_index(["key1", "id"]));`

Comment: Did you save the df as csv first and then reload it? I had done `df2.id = df2.id.astype("object")` and `df_loaded.combine_first(df2.set_index(["key1", "id"]))`, but I just tried your code (with semicolon on one line) and I get the same garbled index result.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you used `str` instead of `object`. Just tried and it works indeed. Any idea why it only works with `str`?

Comment: that's because int is a subtype of object. When you ask pandas to convert int to object, it will still be stored as an int. Asking it to be converted to str will force it to be str. Is that clear or should I add an example?

Comment: No that's clear, thanks. I guess you could add your solution as an answer so I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the `id` column to `str`, not `object`, before combining.

This will work:

```
df2.id = df2.id.astype(str)
df_loaded.combine_first(df2.set_index(["key1", "id"]))
```